# Probability of guessing M&M colors correctly

Tags: probability

Suppose there are 5 M and M beans of different colors. You randomly choose 3. What is the probability that you guess 2 out of the 3 numbers correctly?

Apparently the answer is $12/125$, but I don't see where this came from.

Here is my take on this. Consider the 3 selected beans. What is the probability that you guess 2 out of the 3 correctly? To guess 2 correctly, there are $\binom{3}{2}$ different pairs you can guess correctly. For each pair, there is a $\frac{1}{5} \cdot \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{2}{3}$ probability of guessing it correctly. So I believe the answer should be

$$
\binom{3}{2} \frac{1}{5} \cdot \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{2}{3} = \frac{1}{10}
$$

Am I thinking about this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both answers, the order of the candies appears to be relevant.  The difference between the answers has to do with the strategy for guessing.  In your answer, you are not repeating your guesses.  In the given answer the guesses are made independently and guesses may be repeated (*despite this lowering the probability, as shown*).

Note $\frac{12}{125}=3\cdot \frac{1}{5}\cdot \frac{1}{5}\cdot \frac{4}{5}$

Which answer is "more correct?"  Without more context, I would have leaned towards your answer myself as it is commonly assumed that such guessing would be done in an optimal way that maximizes chances of success.

Comment: Ah there it is. So my strategy is slightly better, it seems? Can you come up with an even better guessing strategy?

Comment: Yes, since $\frac{12}{125}<\frac{12}{120}=\frac{1}{10}$.  As for an even better strategy?  I'm rather certain there isn't one.

Comment: This does, of course, assume that the problem should be interpreted as the candies are all five different colors and we know those five colors.  If we were instead told that a certain set of five colors are possible but each candy in the bag were randomly assigned a color independently of one another (*so it is possible that all five candies are red for instance*), then the given answer would have been correct and you incorrect.  That is not how I read it however.